# How to send json result as a Dictionary instead of Array in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to send response as a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "id": 5928101,
    "category": "animal welfare",
    "organizer": "Adam",
    "title": "Cat Cabaret",
    "description": "Yay felines!",
    "location": "Meow Town",
    "date": "2019-01-03T21:54:00.000Z",
    "time": "2:00",
}
```

But I am using bellow code, which results an array

```
var ress = JSON.stringify(sqlResults)
console.log('response json:' + ress)
res.send(ress)
```

The resulted array has brackets [] like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 5928101,
        "category": "animal welfare",
        "organizer": "Adam",
        "title": "Cat Cabaret",
        "description": "Yay felines!",
        "location": "Meow Town",
        "date": "2019-01-03T21:54:00.000Z",
        "time": "2:00",
    }
]
```

How can I send result without a third bracket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return the first element of your `sqlResults` array you should get the result you wish.

You should also be able to use res.json(dict) to send your result to the client.

```js
sqlResults = [
    {
        "id": 5928101,
        "category": "animal welfare",
        "organizer": "Adam",
        "title": "Cat Cabaret",
        "description": "Yay felines!",
        "location": "Meow Town",
        "date": "2019-01-03T21:54:00.000Z",
        "time": "2:00",
    }
];

const dict = sqlResults[0];
var ress = JSON.stringify(dict, null, 2)
console.log('response json:' + ress)

// You can then send using res.send(ress);
// Or simply res.json(dict);
```